# Is it possible to read correctly text file with wrong BOM in C#?

Tags: c#, text, encoding

I have a text file that has wrong BOM (FF FE, but the real encoding of text is ISO-8859-9).
I try this code:

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9");
string content = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Documents\test.txt", encoding);
```

But it doesn't work - the charset is broken.
Can anybody help me to read this file?

Comment: Remove BOM then try.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work", *precisely*? If it's just that the first two characters are incorrect, just use Substring.

Comment: That code should work, but you will get two trashy chars at the beginning, if all the encoding is wrong then it's encoding is different.

Comment: Just `var data = File.ReadAllBytes("file path"); var content = encoding.GetString(data, 2, data.Length - 2);`.

Comment: How did that file end-up like this is your actual problem I think.

Comment: This broken file was created intentionally to check the tested application ability to process such files (it just ignores BOM).
It seems, removing BOM is the only solution. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Adriano already mentioned in his comment, you probably need to skip the first two bytes of the file. This can be done by using

```
byte[] rawdata = File.ReadAllBytes("...");
byte[] correctedRawdata = rawdata.Skip(2).ToArray();
Encoding encoder = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9");

string text = encoder.GetString(correctedRawdata);
```